# Merge Sort not working correctly with certain list of numbers

Tags: c++, mergesort

It works correctly with the second list of numbers but not the first, why is this? What can I do to correct it? What is the minimal change I can make to fix this? I have learned this off and now I've come to the realisation it is not fully correct...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int start, int len) {
    int size = (len - start) + 1;
    int* b = new int[size]();
    int i = start;
    int mid = (start + len) / 2;
    int k = 0;
    int j = mid + 1;

    while (k < size) {
        if ((i <= mid) && (arr[i] < arr[j])) {
            b[k++] = arr[i++];
        }
        else {
            b[k++] = arr[j++];
        }
    }

    for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        arr[start + k] = b[k];
    }

    delete[] b;
}

void mergeSort(int data[], int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(data, start, mid);
        mergeSort(data, mid + 1, end);
        merge(data, start, end);
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size) {
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Printing ordered array of integers after merge sort" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int data[10] = { 2, 4, 3, 1, 7, 9, 8, 6, 5, 10 };
    mergeSort(data, 0, 9);
    printArray(data, 10);

    //Merge Sort and Merge
    cout << "Calling Merge and Merge Sort Recursive Functions\n"
        "with array of 10 integers" << endl;
    int arrayOfInts[10] = { 10, 23, 34, 2, 56, 42, 78, 4, 84, 99 };
    mergeSort(arrayOfInts, 0, 9);

    printArray(arrayOfInts, 10);
    system("pause");
}
```

The first array produces `1,2,3,1,5,6,5,7,8,10` and the second array produces a sorted array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
if ((i <= mid) && (arr[i] < arr[j]))
```

You need to make sure `i` is `<=` than `mid` **and `j` is `<=` than `len`**. If either `i` or `j` is out of range then doing a comparison is undefined behavior, but also doing a comparison is not useful.

Once you get one value out of range you then copy values from the the other side.

```
// Copy and compare while both i and j are in range.
while (i <= mid && j <= len) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
        b[k++] = arr[i++];
    }
    else {
        b[k++] = arr[j++];
    }
}
// Copy remaining from fist range (could be zero)
while(i <= mid) {
    b[k++] = arr[i++];
}
// Copy remaining from second range (could be zero)
while(j <= len) {
    b[k++] = arr[j++];
}
```

Now that the code is fixed. There are several best practice issue you need to resolve. But for that you should take the code to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you so much, saved me a lot of effort. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `merge()` function is implemented incorrectly and thus not called with proper arguments in `mergesort()` on last line, where it should be called with: `merge(data, start, mid, end);`

Looking over Wikipedia and just a general understanding of the algorithm we can rewrite it a bit so we get this:

```
void mergeSort(int data[], int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergeSort(data, start, mid);
        mergeSort(data, mid + 1, end);
        merge(data, start, mid, end); // Changed this line to include the mid.
    }
}
```

And then rewrite the `merge()` function itself so it conforms to new argument requirements like so:

```
void merge(int arr[], int start, int mid, int len) {
  int i, j, k;
  int n1 = mid - start + 1; 
  int n2 =  len - mid; 
  // Create temporary arrays and copy data to them.
  int lefthalf[n1], righthalf[n2]; 
  for (i = 0; i < n1; i++){
    lefthalf[i] = arr[start + i]; 
  }
  for (j = 0; j < n2; j++){ 
    righthalf[j] = arr[mid + 1+ j]; 
  }
  // Merge temporary arrays back into main array.
  i = 0; // Initial index of left half.
  j = 0; // Initial index of right half.
  k = start; // Initial index of merged subarray 
  while (i < n1 && j < n2) 
  { 
    if (lefthalf[i] <= righthalf[j]) 
    { 
      arr[k] = lefthalf[i]; 
      i++; 
    } 
    else
    { 
      arr[k] = righthalf[j]; 
      j++; 
    } 
    k++; 
  } 
  // If anything left in left half, copy it over and increment accordingly.
  while (i < n1) 
  { 
    arr[k] = lefthalf[i]; 
    i++; 
    k++; 
  } 
  // Copy anything left in right half accordingly and increment.
  while (j < n2) 
  { 
    arr[k] = righthalf[j]; 
    j++; 
    k++; 
  } 
}
```

After these changes, the code results in both fully sorted arrays correctly.

Comment: I just realized after reading the other answer that I didn't spot the actual error, but this is also a valid way to rewrite the code and delivers intended results so I'll leave it here.

Comment: Worth taking this answer to https://codereview.stackexchange.com to get some hints on best practice.